# Not able to register for Sales Cloud Consultant certification?

Tags: certification, sales-cloud

I have a Platform Developer 1 certification and a DEV401 certification . Currently i have applied for Platform App Builder Transition Certification . 
I am unable to register for Sales Cloud exam ? do you please what might be the reason ?

So i again do Administration certification also in order to take Sales Cloud certification ?

Comment: You must be certified admin first.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good question to ask the certification team directly. They have been changing the prerequisites for the certifications recently so a direct question on why you cannot register they would be better positioned to answer.

http://certification.salesforce.com/